# What would be the appropriate syntax for clicking the "send to" drop down menu? (See image for reference)

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I would like to know what the best syntax would be to click the"send to" button on the web page.

[image]

Here's the code so far:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Search_PubMedandCochrane()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed"

Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Loop

Debug.Print IE.LocationName, IE.LocationURL

IE.Document.forms("EntrezForm").elements("term").Value = Range("B4")

IE.Document.forms("EntrezForm").elements("search").Click



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) CSS selector to target the element by an attribute and its value.

```
IE.document.querySelector("[sourcecontent='send_to_menu']").click
```

Make sure you have a sufficient page load wait before trying to click. As a minimum you need

```
While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend 
IE.document.querySelector("[sourcecontent='send_to_menu']").click
```

You could also use

```
IE.document.querySelector("#sendto > a").click
```